# how to use .load(function() { on a large function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, css

I have 5 pretty large CSS3 / jQuery chain animations within a web page, these occur at 5 subpages, when the user navigates to each individual (5) subpages..

I would like to use / have the effect of jQuery's

```
$( img ).load(function() {
  // Run code
});
```

Except I only want to check if the images are fully loaded **within** each function.. And if they are loading / still loading display a simple '*spinning animation gif*' in place of my animation within that function; once all images within the animation function LOAD, then display the animation and `.hide();` the `spinner.gif`

```
function one() {

// tons of animation code
```

**Images are in the CSS** as background images (css3 animations; the jQuery are mostly setting the triggers)

Comment: the images are dynamically added to the page or are in the original HTML?

Comment: they are dynamically; about 90% are within the CSS

Comment: You can't really listen to onload on images that are inside CSS. I would say that there is no way to do this in a maintainable manner. On the other hand you could use $(window).load() to fire when the page is fully loaded (including your images that are inside CSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would want multiple deferred objects to pass them into `$.when()`. I believe you're looking for something like this:

```
var d1 = new $.Deferred();
var d2 = new $.Deferred();
var d3 = new $.Deferred();

$.when(d1, d2, d3).then(function() {
   // perform your animations here
});

$(img1).load(function() {
  d1.resolve();
}

$(img2).load(function() {
  d2.resolve();
}

$(img3).load(function() {
  d3.resolve();
}
```

Comment: I take it you didnt mean to resolve `d1` three times, so I updated your code.

Comment: Nice way to deal with deferred however, is there a way to solve for `n` in this case though ?